# SQL: return all rows that contain more than two identical absolute values in a column grouped by another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following content:

| Batch | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 250 |
| 1 | -250 |
| 1 | 250 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 3 | 100 |
| 3 | 100 |

There may be a different number of rows for each batch, the values of 'Amount' are random and may contain positive or negative numbers.

I need to return Batches for which there are more than two identical absolute values of Amount (in the example above that would be batch 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a `group by` & `having`:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (batch, amount) as
  2    (select 1,  250 from dual union all
  3     select 1, -250 from dual union all
  4     select 1,  250 from dual union all
  5     select 1,  100 from dual union all
  6     select 2,   50 from dual union all
  7     select 3,  100 from dual union all
  8     select 3,  100 from dual
  9    )
```

Query:

```
 10  select batch
 11  from test
 12  group by batch, abs(amount)
 13  having count(*) > 2;

     BATCH
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks you, that's it